# Micronaut service not responding to request

Tags: java, microservices, micronaut

I have a (relatively simple) Micronaut service that I am seeking to pass a parameter to. The code for the service is below:

```
package com.factor3.app;


import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/testserv")
public class TempTestService
{
   public TempTestService()
   {
   }

   @Get("/{?theData}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String performService(String theData)
   {
       return("Returning: "+theData));
   }

}
```

I have set my port to 8090 in the application.yml file:

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: TSBroker

#Uncomment to set server port
    server:
        port: 8090
```

There are no other controllers, beans, or filters.

I have been running this service and attempting to access it from a browser, using the following URI:

http://localhost:8090/testserv?theData=xxx

After several minutes, I get the following failure on Google Chrome:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Am I missing something? Why does this page not work?

Thanks in advance for any insights...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things about your code that won't even compile.  If you change your class to look like the following it will compile and will respond to http://localhost:8090/testserv?theData=xxx.

```
package com.factor3.app;

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

@Controller("/testserv")
public class TempTestService
{
    // this empty constructor isn't necessary, but
    // also doesn't cause a problem...
   public TempTestService()
   {
   }

   @Get("/{?theData}")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String performService(@Nullable String theData)
   {
       return "Returning: "+theData;
   }
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/jeffbrown/factorthreedemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/factor3/app/TempTestService.java

Comment: what has changed except `@Nullable`?

Comment: There was an extraneous closing paren in `return("Returning: "+theData));`.  `@Nullable` needed to be added to the `theData` param and an import statement had to be added for `javax.annotation.Nullable`.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I accidentally added an extra ")" when I was copying and editing the code for entry into this forum.